# Decoupled Deployment of Web App using Heroku, gh-pages, and MySQL

Tags: heroku, deployment, github-pages, package.json

My team and I created a MERN stack application (M for MySQL) that is planning on hosting our client on gh-pages and our server on heroku. So far we have been unable to deploy because we keep getting errors about our use of the npm package concurrently. Although we can access our heroku url and our gh-pages url, we are unable to connect the two

We have already tried adding a proxy to our package.json within our client folder and have added a .env.development Host name (heroku url)

Root Directory
- client
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
- config
  - config.json
  - passport.json
- controllers
- models
- routes
- .env
- .env.development
- .gitignore
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- server.js

Server package.json

```
{
  "name": "traveler",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": "http://dchicchon.github.io/Traveler",
  "description": "A social media platform for people who love traveling and those who want to explore.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:prod": "node server.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"npm run client\"",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "seed": "node scripts/seedDB.js",
    "install": "cd client && npm install",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.511.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.5",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^5.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/dchicchon/Traveler.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/dchicchon/Traveler/issues"
  }
}
```

Client package.json

```
{
  "name": "traveler",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "https://travelersite.herokuapp.com/",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

After entering the command heroku create and git push heroku master we would expect that our server will be pushed to heroku and our client will be deployed to gh-pages.

Answer (score 0):

Does removing heroku-postbuild script from your backend package.json work?